# my project is somehow using the wrong python

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I keep getting these errors

```
^C(trydjango)apples-MacBook-Pro:src ray$ ./manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x108f612a8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 10, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 19, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 417, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 410, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/2 trydjango jan 30 ajax search/src/try/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    from posts import views
  File "/Users/ray/Desktop/mypy/2 trydjango jan 30 ajax search/src/posts/views.py", line 1, in <module>
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus
ImportError: No module named parse
```

How can I switch it back to using the right interpreter. When I try to switch it and select 3.5  nothing changes

welcoming all help. lots of hours on this project that was almost done.

it's using my macs python instead of 3.5

Comment: Check the [IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html)

Answer (score 0):

urllib.parse was added in Python 3.  You need to upgrade your Mac from Python 2.7 to Python 3.

Open terminal.

xcode-select --install

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

add this to your $HOME/.bash_profile

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

then,
source $HOME/.bash_profile

then,
brew install python3

check the install with,
python3 --version

Comment: I've read that't not good to do, and that there are reasons that apple doesn't have the most current python. and besides tha, i'd like to know how to get pycharm to use the correct path

Comment: Well, python3 can break some python2 scripts, yes.  pycharm works as well.  go into the pycharm default settings, and you can choose the project interpreter under Default Project.  after you change python versions, make sure that the python version you want is the first location found in your PATH environment variable.